# Use a c# function in a crm form onload/onclick

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I've created a button on a CRM form and now when I click on it I want to send some info to a function that has been written in C# and then do some calculations.

My question is how to use this function from a CRM onclick event.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is; you can't do what you ask.  At least, not directly.  You need to wrap your C# function in a web service and call the web service from the CRM form/button using JavaScript.

This blog post (an others on this site) could help you get started:

http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/10/18/calling-aspnet-webservice-from-javascript-ajax/